# SpringData: How Map AngularJS page with @RepositoryRestResource?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I follow this tutorial about Data Accessing:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

So, I have this structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUnrx.png

"Project" is the Model

```
package Serveur;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String mail;
    private String password;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

And the interface "ProjectRepository", which implemented directly by the "@RepositoryRestResource" annotation

package Serveur;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "jsonProjects", path = "jsonProjects")
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project, Integer> {

    List<Project> findById(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

The "Home Controller" contains a @RequestMapping Annotation and redirects the user to "index" page :

```
package Serveur;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index()
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

But, when I connect to localhost:8080/ , the index page does not display but this:

```
{
   _links: {
     jsonProjects: {
         href: "http://localhost:8080/jsonProjects{?page,size,sort}",
         templated: true
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the @RepositoryRestResource annotation binds to "/". To fix your issue, edit Application.java and add this function:

```
@Override
      protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
        try {
          config.setBaseUri(new URI("/api"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

Your HomeController will not bind to "/" and your API's will be available at "/api"

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer:

By default all Repository search function comes after search keyword.  So in your case URL will be something like:
http://localhost:PORT/APP/jsonProjects/search/findById?name=NAME

See my working example and blog for the same:

http://sv-technical.blogspot.com/2015/11/spring-boot-and-repositoryrestresource.html

https://github.com/svermaji/Spring-boot-with-hibernate-no-controller

Hope this helps.